# how to stop syslog messages to write console on solaris

Tags: solaris, syslog

how to stop syslog messages to write console on solaris ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can edit the entries in the `/etc/syslog.conf` to direct to another file eg `/var/log/syslog` instead of `/dev/console`. After that, issue `kill -HUP <pid of syslog daemon>` to "reinitialize" the config

Answer (score 1):

it should be

svcadm disable svc:/system/system-log:default

Answer (score 1):

svcadm disable svc:/system/system-log:default turned syslog off you need to also run svcadm enable svc:/system/system-log:default to turn it back on, after you made the right changes to /etc/syslog.conf  so it does what you want. You can probably just comment out the line as it is also logged to file in /var/adm/messages.log

Turning syslog off is not a good idea.